# Filter and get all the customers who had brought the authors other contents to send the notification when new content is added

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I want to Filter and get all the customers who had brought the authors other contents to send the notification when new content is added This works on queryset I know but I'm Confused on how to do that. If anyone please share.

Here are my models

content:

```
 class Content(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    Author = models.ForeignKey('User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, null=False)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='course', default='nocover.jpg')
    catogary = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    requirements = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
```

Puchased content

```
 class PurchasedContent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, blank=True, related_name='course')
```

I want all the list of Customers email who had brought a particular Authors course
the Author will be authenticated while adding. We'll get the Author as request.user

Here is sample ListCreateAPIView in django rest Framework

```
class createlistcontentview(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope]
queryset = Content.objects.all()
serializer_class = ContentSerializer



def perform_create(self, serializer):

    #Here I want to get a list of mails to create a Function that sends mall
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: so if I'm getting you right you want to send a notification email when a new content is created right?

Comment: Yes. For the customers who had already brought the other content from the same author

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is use a signal to send the email to the users whenever a content is created like this:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver

# models.py

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=Content)
def send_email(sender, instance:Content, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # import and use your email helper here
        # since the related name you chose for the purchased_content course is a little confusing I changed it to `purchased_content`
        purchases = instance.course.purchased_content.all()
        send_email(users=[user.email for user in purchases])
        return
```